# In Java, pass large double as parameter to sql server, causing "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm using `Spring Jdbc` to make insertion with `Sql Server`. But recently I have a large double with more than 10 digits (let say `11123456789.00`), which becomes `1.1123456789E10` when I print it out without the formatting.

Here is how I pass it to Sql Server:

```
double largeDouble = 11123456789.00;
MapSqlParameterSource paraMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
paraMap.addValue("largeDouble", largeDouble);

SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate());
simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("someStoredProcedure").execute(paraMap);
```

The data type of `largeDouble` field in Sql Server is `decimal(19,2)`.

And this error shows "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." after running the program.

I'm wondering why this situation happens and how to solve it.

Comment: what is your database table structure like? provide also stored procedure's body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I manage to find the program, which is the xml parameter of a large Double. In xml, it become a number with scientific notation, violate the numeric type of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Try the other method with extra parameter to specify the SQL type.

```
paraMap.addValue("largeDouble", largeDouble, Types.LONG);
```

Comment: do you mean `java.sql.Types`? Why isn't it a `Types.DOUBLE`